# Как посчитать сумму ячеек, в зависимости от значений в соседних ячейках?

Tags: excel, excel-формулы

Подскажите, как посчитать сумму всех ячеек, у которых справа указана дополнительная информация?

Например посчитать сколько всего потрачено на еду.

[image: Что-то из серии]

Comment: Нужен пример и описание проблемы. Но думаю , тут могут подойти сводные таблицы

Comment: http://www.planetaexcel.ru/techniques/8/132/

Answer (score 2):

1. Используйте Сводные таблицы как универсальный способ;
2. Если локально для Вашего вопросФункция `СУММЕСЛИ([диапазон]; [критерий]; [диапазон_суммирования])`

Вышеописанный пример с формулами выглядит следующим образом:
[image: Финальная таблица]

Для начала создали дополнительный столбец 'Итого' для каждой строки:
[image: Суммируем строки]

Далее провели суммирование с применением функции 'СУММЕСЛИ'
[image: Формула СУММЕСЛИ]

PS.
Сводные таблицы - универсальный способ

Comment: Добавьте пример пожалуйста, как будет выглядеть функция для ячеек в примере автора вопроса.

Answer (score 1):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

если D1 = A2 истина, то присваиваем значение B2, если ложь то присваиваем 0. А в конце сумма этого столбца.

Answer (score 1):

Допонительные формулы часто помогают разгрузить вычисления, но в данном случае оптимальнее без доп. столбца - cуммировать результаты работы двух функций:

```
=СУММЕСЛИ($D$2:$D$6;E7;$A$2:$A$6)+СУММЕСЛИ($D$2:$D$6;E7;$B$2:$B$6)
```

' ---------------------

Вариант с использованием формулы массива (ФМ):

```
=СУММ(ЕСЛИ($D$2:$D$6=E7;$A$2:$B$6))
```

ФМ вводится сочетанием трех клавиш *Ctrl+Shift+Enter*. Если введена правильно, в строке формул ФМ видна в окружении фигурных скобок.

Для данной задачи применение ФМ не оправдано, но зачастую ФМ здорово помогают.

' ---------------------

Следующая формула не является формулой массива (не нужен "трехпальцевый" ввод), работает быстрее показанной конструкции *СУММ(ЕСЛИ...*, но тоже делает много лишних движений:

```
 =СУММПРОИЗВ(($D$2:$D$6=E7)*ИНДЕКС($A$2:$B$6;;))
```